# USA - Going on exchange on a J-1 Visa, how to stay more than 30 days after end

Tags: visas, exchange

I am an Australian applying for a J-1 visa to go on exchange at a Uni in the US for the spring semester of 2019. This visa allows me to stay for 30 days after the program ends on the 10th of May, but I would like to go to a big bluegrass music festival takes place just outside the 30 day limit.

I have found 2 possibilities so far:

1. Apply for J-1, leave for Canada within the 30 days and attempt to reenter with the Visa Waiver Program (risky), see post: https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/22902445
2. Apply for J-1 and B-2 visa at the same time before going to US???

As this will be a once in a lifetime experience, I would really like to make this happen. What options are there to stay for longer? I have not applied for the J-1 visa yet as I am seeking advice on this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: B2 is going be no better than the VWP, will still be up to the immigration officer on arrival. If you have a ticket home and tickets to the festival I can't see a good reason with your story why you won't be allowed in. I returned to the USA for 90 days on VWP after doing a summer camp job on a J1 visa, I got a few more questions than usual but was honest about my intentions and was let in. Obviously that is dependent on the immigration officer.

Comment: Also if you arrive to the US by road from Canada you don't need to apply for an ESTA. Although some people say it gets them through the border quicker.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Is it fair to say that if I wish to extend my stay, it will have to involve travelling to Canada within the 30 day Grace period of the J1? So you came back during the J1 grace period and were able to use the VWP?

Comment: @BritishSam B2 *is* better than the VWP in certain respects, but none that would be particularly helpful in this case.  Rob: to change from J-1 status to B-2 status you would also have to leave the US and reenter, or you could file an in-country change-of-status application, in which case you would not need a B-2 visa in your passport.  The rules on COS applications have changed recently, though, so I need to do some research before I can post a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment phoog. Any clarification on the COS application thing would be appreciated.

Comment: And to change from J-1 to B-2 by temporarily leaving the US, will I need to have both visas already issued in Australia, then the B-2 would automatically be my new status when I reenter the US from Canada? I'm trying to get my head around this.

Comment: The change of status is form [I-539](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539) which costs $370, much more than a visa, and possibly more than a return ticket to Canada.

Comment: Also, if your J-1 has a 2-year home residency requirement, you cannot do Change of Status in the US.